# Fluent Nhibernate - How to persist collection of new entities with single database call

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent

I have a process where I create multiple new entities.  I've tried adding them to a collection (doing a .Persist() on them), and then when my collection is ready, trying to commit the transaction.

I've checked to make sure that no database calls are being executed until I call Transaction.Commit(), but once I call commit, I see calls being made for each individual entity.

Is there a way to save an entire collection of same-type entities at once?

Answer (score 2):

Have you set the batch size?

http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/16/BatchingSupportInNHibernate.aspx

in your fluent config try setting the

.AdoNetBatchSize(10)

http://fluentnhibernate.org/api/FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db/PersistenceConfiguration%602.htm

hope this helps you.

Comment: Note that the capability to perform batching is also dependent on your specific database provider. For example, this is not possible (AFAIK) in SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

Also for inserts if you are using `Identity` as primary key Nhibernate won't be able to batch inserts.